# CONCAT With ROLLUP

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to combine the first and last name columns while using a rollup but it seems to copy the same last name onto every firstname:

```
SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname),'Total Projects') AS Name, count(DISTINCT(p.id) ) AS Total
FROM projects p
INNER JOIN users u ON p.creator_fk = u.id
GROUP BY Name WITH ROLLUP;
```

So I end up with something like:

```
Name           | Total

John Smith     | 10
Sarah Smith    | 25
Tracy Smith    | 5
Total Projects | 40
```

Comment: Do you want to rollup by firstname and lastname??

Comment: I believe you can't use alias in group by, instead put the concatenation statement in group by.

Comment: No I want the count(p.id) to rollup

Comment: You should not use `IFNULL()` (let the query return `NULL` for the summary row added by `WITH ROLLUP`; replace it with anything you want in the client code). Also, it's better to `GROUP BY u.id`.

Comment: @Lamar: You can in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding

```
SELECT IFNULL(name,'Total Projects') AS Name, count(DISTINCT(id)) AS Total 
from  (select CONCAT(u.firstname,' ', u.lastname) as name,p.id
    FROM projects p INNER JOIN users u ON p.creator_fk = u.id) as p  GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: That works for stopping the last name being copied over but at the bottom where 'Total Projects' should be it has the last name in the list instead.

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: So it works but the last person on the list's name is where 'Total projects' should be. So in the example I showed above "Tracy" is listed twice, once with her own total and also with the rollup total.

Comment: I modified it plz check once

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to concat first and last name without duplicating entries in the resulting table.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(name, 'TOTAL') as name,
  COUNT(ticket_number) as tickets
FROM
  ( SELECT
      CONCAT(emp_last, ', ', emp_first) as name, ticket_number
    FROM
      project_tickets_table
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      employees ON project_tickets_table.emp=employees.empl_id
    WHERE
      status in ('ACTI', 'ASSG') ) as p
GROUP BY ROLLUP (name)
ORDER BY cases DESC
```

Note the `as p` part is *required*, but doesn't do anything in this case. You can change `p` to anything you want, as long as you include `as something`.